# Как в DataGridView добавить в заголовок колонки ComboBox?

Tags: c#, datagridview

Не для всей колонки сделать тип ComboBox, а только для заголовка.

Comment: Зачем? Чего вы этим хотите добиться?

Comment: Заполнять колонку в зависимости от выбранного варианта в комбобоксе.

Comment: Заголовок должен быть заголовком и ничем иным. Просто разместите этот комбобокс рядом на форме.